# How to store functions of a dynamic class?

Tags: python-3.x, database, class, serialization, dynamic

I have python classes which should be dynamically loaded during run-time. A class can have various attributes and functions. I create such classes with `type`:

```py
my_class = type("ClassName", (object, ), {'string_attr': "My String", 
                                          'int_attr': 42,
                                          'my_function': lambda self, a, b: a+b})
```

All the information about the class (name, parent, attributes, functions) should be stored in a persistent layer (database). This allows me to modify the attributes and functions.

Now to my problem: Obviously, I cannot store the lambda expression (an object) in a database. There, I see two approaches:

- First, I store the lambda expression as a string representation. Unfortunately, this requires me to evaluate the lambda strings with `eval()` when I generate my class.
- Second, I serialize the lambda expression and store it. Whenever I want to generate my class, I have to deserialize the lambda expression.

In both approaches, I have to distinguish between the attributes and functions. The attributes are directly convertible, while the functions need further treatment.

Is my approach completely wrong? Are there any good alternatives?

Comment: What is the usecase you are trying to solve by putting this in a database? You can serialize and deserialize python objects using pickle which may help you but I don't know the usecase you are trying to achieve and why you are trying to throw a string representation of a python class into a database. Pickle can be vulnerable if reading from an untrusted source but can serialize and deserialize objects, i.e. it serialize an entire class (since a class is an object in python).

Comment: Finally, I will work with a NoSql database for which I need a dynamic python representation (model). The goal is to have various models which can be defined and adapted by the user. The advantage of the string representation is to see the content of the table in the databse (although it is not as elegant).

Comment: I guess I still don't understand everything. Can you add anything that may help me? An input and output would be useful or maybe python code showing how you expect it to work. Even detailed psuedo code would be helpful. (Emphasis on detailed).